# PreFlow Push - Array out of bounds for Graph input

Tags: java, algorithm, graph

I have implemented Pre Flow Push in Java. I am getting array out of bounds exception when I input a random graph. Can someone explain to me why I am getting this exception and how to fix it?

*I am able to get the flow value for Bipartite Graphs, but not for any other type of graphs*

```
    public class PreFlowPush {

    public class Height {

    private int itemCount;
    private int maxHeightIndex;
    private final LinkedList<Vertex>[] list;

    public int getMaxHeightIndex() {
        return maxHeightIndex;
    }

    public Height(int n){
        this.itemCount = 0;

        this.maxHeightIndex = 0;

        list = new LinkedList[n];

        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            list[i] = new LinkedList<Vertex>();
        }
    }

    public boolean isEmpty(){
        return itemCount == 0;
    }

    public void add(int index, Vertex v){
        list[index].add(v);
        if(index > maxHeightIndex){
            maxHeightIndex = index;
        }
        itemCount++;
    }

    public void remove(int index, Vertex v){
        list[index].remove(v);
        if(maxHeightIndex == index && list[index].size() == 0) {
            while (maxHeightIndex >= 0) {
                if(list[maxHeightIndex].size() != 0){
                    break;
                }
                maxHeightIndex--;
            }
        }
        itemCount--;
    }

    public boolean contains(int index, Vertex v){
        return list[index].contains(v);
    }

    public Vertex getFirst(int index){
        return list[index].getFirst();
    }

    public int getListSize(int index){
        return list[index].size();
    }

}

public class Vertex_data {
    private int height;
    private int excess;
    public Node current;
    public edgeList edgeLinkedList;


    public Vertex_data(Iterator<Edge> edgeIterator){ 
        this.height = 0;
        this.excess = 0;

        edgeLinkedList = new edgeList();



        while(edgeIterator.hasNext()){
            Edge e = edgeIterator.next();
            edgeLinkedList.put(e);
        }

        this.current = edgeLinkedList.getFirst();
    }

    public int getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public void setHeight(int height) {
        this.height = height;
    }

    public int getExcess() {
        return excess;
    }

    public void setExcess(int excess) {
        this.excess = excess;
    }

    public boolean hasExcess(){
        return excess > 0;
    }
}
    public class Edge_Data {
    private int flow = 0;
    private final int capacity;

    public Edge forwardEdge;
    public Edge backwardEdge;

    public Edge_Data(int capacity, Vertex v, Vertex w, String name){

        this.capacity = capacity;

        this.forwardEdge = new Edge(v, w, capacity - flow, "forward");
        this.backwardEdge = new Edge(w, v, flow, "backward");
    }

    public int getFlow() {
        return flow;
    }

    public void setFlow(int flow) {
        this.flow = flow;
        setForward();
        setBackward();
    }

    public int getCapacity() {
        return capacity;
    }


    public void setForward(){
        forwardEdge.setData(capacity-flow);
    }

    public void setBackward(){
        backwardEdge.setData(flow);
    }

    public Integer getForwardCapacity(){
        return (Integer) forwardEdge.getData();
    }

    public Integer getBackwardCapacity() {
        return (Integer) backwardEdge.getData();
    }

    public boolean hasForwardEdge(){
        return !forwardEdge.getData().equals(0);
    }

    public boolean hasBackwardEdge(){
        return !backwardEdge.getData().equals(0);
    }
}
    public class edgeList {
    private Node head;

    /**
     * Gets the Node  for a given Edge
     *
     * @param Edge
     * @return  for a search hit or null for a search miss
     */
    public Node get(Edge Edge) {
        Node current = head;

        while (current != null) {
            if (Edge.equals(current.Edge)) {
                return current;
            }

            current = current.next;
        }

        return null;
    }

    public Node getFirst(){
        return head;
    }

    /**
     * puts a Edge- pair at the beginning of the list
     *
     * @param Edge
     */
    public void put(Edge Edge) {
        for (Node current = head; current != null; current = current.next) {
            if (Edge.equals(current.Edge)) {
                return;
            }
        }
        head = new Node(Edge, head);
    }

    /**
     * Lazy deletion of the Node with a given Edge
     *
     * @param Edge given Edge
     * @throws NullPointerException if the given Edge is not found in the list
     */
    public void delete(Edge Edge) {

        Node currentPrevious = null;
        Node current = head;

        while (current != null) {
            if (Edge.equals(current.Edge)) {


                if (current == head) {
                    head = head.next;
                    current.next = null;
                    return;
                } else {

                    currentPrevious.next = current.next;
                    current.next = null;

                    return;
                }
            }

            currentPrevious = current;
            current = current.next;
        }

        throw new NullPointerException("The given Edge is not present in the list!");
    }


}
public class Node {
    Edge Edge;
    Node next;

    public Node(Edge Edge, Node nextNode) {
        this.Edge = Edge;
        this.next = nextNode;
    }

    public Edge getEdge(){
        return this.Edge;
    }

    public Node getNext(){
        return this.next;
    }
}
    private final SimpleGraph graph;
    private final Height heights;

    public PreFlowPush(SimpleGraph graph){
        this.graph = graph;
        heights = new Height(graph.numVertices()+1);

        initialize();
    }

    public int preflow_push(){
        int Flow_Value = 0;
        boolean can_push = false;
        boolean can_relabel = false;
        Vertex v = heights.getFirst(heights.getMaxHeightIndex());

        while(!heights.isEmpty()) {

            Vertex_data vData = (Vertex_data) v.getData();
            Node current = vData.current;

            while(vData.hasExcess()) {
                while (current != null) {
                    Edge e = current.getEdge();
                    Edge_Data eData = (Edge_Data) e.getData();
                    Vertex w = graph.opposite(v, e);
                    Vertex_data wData = (Vertex_data) w.getData();

                    can_push = push(v, vData, w, wData, e, eData);

                    if (can_push) {
                        if (!vData.hasExcess()) {
                            if (eData.getCapacity() != eData.getFlow()) {
                                break;
                            } else {
                                if (vData.current.next != null) {
                                    vData.current = vData.current.getNext();
                                }
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    current = current.getNext();
                }

                if (!can_push) {
                    can_relabel = relabel(v, vData);
                    if (can_relabel) {
                        vData.current = vData.edgeLinkedList.getFirst();
                        current = vData.current;
                    } else {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            if(heights.isEmpty()){
                break;
            }
            v = heights.getFirst(heights.getMaxHeightIndex());
        }

        Iterator vertexIterator = graph.vertices();
        while(vertexIterator.hasNext()){
            Vertex p = (Vertex) vertexIterator.next();
            if(p.getName().equals("s")){
                Iterator edgeIterator = graph.incidentEdges(p);
                while(edgeIterator.hasNext()){
                    Edge e = (Edge) edgeIterator.next();
                    Edge_Data eData = (Edge_Data) e.getData();
                    Flow_Value += eData.getFlow();
                }
            }
        }

        return Flow_Value;
    }

    private void Height_add(int height, Vertex v){
        Vertex_data vData = (Vertex_data) v.getData();
        if(!v.getName().equals("t") && vData.hasExcess()) {
            heights.add(height, v);
        }
    }

    private void moveToNewHeight(int prevHeight, int newHeight, Vertex v){
        heights.remove(prevHeight, v);
        if(!v.getName().equals("t")) {
            heights.add(newHeight, v);
        }
    }

    private void modifyHeight(Vertex v, Vertex_data vData){
        int height = vData.getHeight();
        if(!vData.hasExcess() && heights.contains(height, v)){
            removeFromHeight(height, v);
        } else{
            if(!heights.contains(height, v)){
                Height_add(height, v);
            }
        }

    }

    private void removeFromHeight(int height, Vertex v){
        heights.remove(height, v);
    }

    private boolean relabel(Vertex v, Vertex_data vData){
        if(vData.getExcess() > 0){
            Iterator<Edge> edgeIterator = (Iterator<Edge>) graph.incidentEdges(v);
            while(edgeIterator.hasNext()){
                Edge e = edgeIterator.next();
                Edge_Data eData = (Edge_Data) e.getData();
                Vertex w = graph.opposite(v, e);
                Vertex_data wData = (Vertex_data) w.getData();

                if(e.getSecondEndpoint().equals(v)){
                    if(!eData.hasBackwardEdge()){
                        continue;
                    }
                } else if(e.getFirstEndpoint().equals(v)){
                    if(!eData.hasForwardEdge()){
                        continue;
                    }
                }

                if(!(wData.getHeight() >= vData.getHeight())){
                    return false;
                }
            }
            moveToNewHeight(vData.getHeight(), vData.getHeight() + 1, v);
            vData.setHeight(vData.getHeight() + 1);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private boolean push(Vertex v, Vertex_data vData, Vertex w, Vertex_data wData, Edge e, Edge_Data eData){
        if(!(vData.getExcess() > 0 && wData.getHeight() < vData.getHeight())){
            return false;
        }
        int delta;
        if(e.getFirstEndpoint().equals(v)){
            if(eData.hasForwardEdge()){
                delta = Math.min(vData.getExcess(), eData.getForwardCapacity());
                eData.setFlow(eData.getFlow() + delta);
                modifyExcess(v, e, vData, eData);
                return true;
            }
        } else if(e.getSecondEndpoint().equals(v)){
            if(eData.hasBackwardEdge()){
                delta = Math.min(vData.getExcess(), eData.getFlow());
                eData.setFlow(eData.getFlow() - delta);
                modifyExcess(v, e, vData, eData);
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;

    }

    private void initialize(){
        Iterator<Vertex> it = (Iterator<Vertex>) graph.vertices();
        Iterator<Edge> edgeIterator = (Iterator<Edge>) graph.edges();

        while(edgeIterator.hasNext()){
            Edge e = edgeIterator.next();
            Double data = (Double) e.getData();
            int capacity = (int) data.doubleValue();
            String name = (String) e.getName();
            Edge_Data eData = new Edge_Data(capacity, e.getFirstEndpoint(), e.getSecondEndpoint(), name);
            e.setData(eData);
        }

        while(it.hasNext()){
            Vertex v = it.next();
            Iterator<Edge> edgeIteratorV = (Iterator<Edge>) graph.incidentEdges(v);
            Vertex_data vData = new Vertex_data(edgeIteratorV);

            if(v.getName().equals("s")){
                continue;
            }

            vData.setHeight(0);
            v.setData(vData);
        }

        it = (Iterator<Vertex>) graph.vertices();
        while(it.hasNext()) {
            Vertex v = it.next();
            Iterator<Edge> edgeIteratorV = (Iterator<Edge>) graph.incidentEdges(v);
            Vertex_data vData = new Vertex_data(edgeIteratorV);

            if (v.getName().equals("s")) {
                v.setData(vData);
                initializeSource(v, vData);
                break;
            }
        }

        edgeIterator = (Iterator<Edge>) graph.edges();

        while(edgeIterator.hasNext()){
            Edge e = edgeIterator.next();
            Edge_Data eData = (Edge_Data) e.getData();

            if(!(e.getFirstEndpoint().getName().equals("s") || e.getSecondEndpoint().getName().equals("s"))){
                eData.setFlow(0);
            }
        }
    }

    private void modifyExcess(Vertex v, Edge e, Vertex_data vData, Edge_Data eData){
        Vertex w = graph.opposite(v, e);

        int excess = eData.getFlow();

        Vertex_data wData = (Vertex_data) w.getData();

        vData.setExcess(vData.getExcess() - excess);
        wData.setExcess(wData.getExcess() + excess);

        modifyHeight(v, vData);
        modifyHeight(w, wData);
    }

    private void initializeSource(Vertex v, Vertex_data vData){
        vData.setHeight(graph.numVertices());
        int Flow_Value = 0;

        Iterator<Edge> edgeIterator = (Iterator<Edge>) graph.incidentEdges(v);
        while(edgeIterator.hasNext()){
            Edge e = edgeIterator.next();
            Edge_Data eData = (Edge_Data) e.getData();
            eData.setFlow(eData.getCapacity());
            modifyExcess(v, e, vData, eData);
            Flow_Value += eData.getFlow();
        }
        if(vData.hasExcess()) {
            Height_add(graph.numVertices(), v);
        }
        Flow_Value = -1*Flow_Value;
        vData.setExcess(Flow_Value);
        v.setData(vData);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleGraph G = new SimpleGraph();
        Vertex s = null;
        Vertex t = null;
        Iterator itr;

        System.out.print("Please enter the full path of input graph: ");
        String userinput;
        userinput = KeyboardReader.readString();
        GraphInput.LoadSimpleGraph(G,userinput);

         itr= G.vertices();
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            Vertex vert = (Vertex) itr.next();
            if (vert.getName().equals("s")) {
                s = vert;
            }else if (vert.getName().equals("t")) {
                t = vert;
            }
        }

        long startTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
        PreFlowPush runPreFlowPush = new PreFlowPush(G);
        long flow = runPreFlowPush.preflow_push();
        long endTime=System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.println("The max flow of this graph is " + flow);
        System.out.println("PFP's running time is " + (endTime - startTime) + "ms");

    }

}
```

Comment: Please create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) this is awful lot of code to read.

Comment: (After digesting [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors?s=3|3.4394), if necessary,) Include relevant parts of the stack trace - such as method/statement where it is thrown.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What causes a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and how do I prevent it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it)